# Using svg:image elements to import a image from the web or internal docs

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm using svg:image to import a image into D3. I thought I was doing it correctly, but it appears not to be working:

```
    d3.selectAll("#chart").append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg ")
    .attr("width", "150px")
    .attr("height", "200px");
```

Here's a visual of the problem - not sure where I have went wrong - http://jsfiddle.net/xwZjN/16/

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the `svg:image` inside your `svg` element. Use this:

```
d3.select("#chart").select("svg").append("svg:image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.e-pint.com/epint.jpg ")
   .attr("width", "150px")
   .attr("height", "200px");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, im now trying to use arc. centroid to plot it in the middle will this be done in a similar manner?

Comment: no that will be slightly different I see that question too .. I'll try to answer